# Proving a Vector Identity involving $\nabla$

Tags: vectors, operator-theory, vector-analysis, vector-fields

> Consider the operator, $\mathbf{L} = -i\hbar\mathbf{r}\times \nabla$ where $i = \sqrt -1$. We need to prove that $\mathbf{L}\times\mathbf{L}f = i\hbar\mathbf{L}f$ , where $f$ is an arbitrary test function.

Applying basic vector identities related to $\nabla$, I have reached the following result:
$\mathbf{L}\times\mathbf{L}f = 2i\mathbf{L}f + \mathbf{r}\times(\mathbf{r}\cdot\nabla)(\nabla f) $
(consider $\hbar = 1$)

I am not able to reduce the second term, any hints are appreciated.

(Preferably without the use of Levi-Civita and brute force expansion)

I had also posted this on Physics SE, but the people there weren't exactly helpful.

Comment: Wow, no answers?